# Laravel differences linux and windows hosting

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

This is very strange: On Windows these functions with exactly the same databases works greats, but when I upload the project to Linux the `pageinfo()` function returns null. Of course the first thing I thought was that this has to do with case sensitivity, but all seems well formatted...

In my Page Model:

```
public function pageinfo() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\PageToElement', 'page_id');
}
```

(The Model PageToElement is exactly called like this)

In my controller:

```
$this->info = Page::find($page->page_id);
$meta = $this->info->pageinfo->where('element_id', 1)->first();
```

On Windows this nicely returns array:

```
App\Models\PageToElement Object (
    [attributes:protected] => Array(
        [id] => 1
        [page_id] => 1
        [element_id] => 1
        [element_parent_id] => 0
        [parent_id] => 0
        [sorting] => 0
        [is_active] => 1
        [created_at] => 2015-12-07 10:00:03
        [updated_at] => 2015-12-07 10:00:03
    )
)
```

But on Linux, the response is `null`

What am I overlooking?

After some research, I came to the conclusion that `$meta = $this->page->pageinfo->where('element_id', 1)->first();` returns `null` on the Linux server. But when I do `$meta = $this->page->pageinfo;` I do get more than one item in return. When I then do `$meta = $this->page->pageinfo->first();` it returns one. So I think somehow the `where('element_id', 1)` is not working for Linux.

But what do you know, `$meta = $this->page->pageinfo->where('element_id', '1')->first();` works! `element_id` is an integer, so why does it need quotes???

Comment: Are you sure the database is not empty?

Comment: 100% sure. Both the linux machine and the windows (local dev) machine use the same external database

Comment: get rid of this: `App\Models\`

Comment: OK, will give it a try... But with other model links this needed to be in there as the namespace is App\Models

Comment: Like I thought, this will produce an error `Class 'PageToElement' not found` even if I add a `use App\Models\PageToElement` line to the Page Model

Comment: Can you `dd($page->page_id)` and `dd($page)` ?

Comment: Also try `Page::find($page->page_id)->first()` instead of `Page::find($page->page_id)`

Comment: Yes `dd($page)` and `dd($page->page_id)` gives one single output like expected

Comment: Try logging all queries in both environments using `DB::getQueryLog()` and see if they are the same

Comment: `where('element_id', 1)` Are you sure the `element_id` is `1` in Database?

Comment: Just a hunch, try running `composer install --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader` and then try again.

Comment: @Roj, I ran the db log and for both servers the query is the same: `select * from `page_to_elements` where `page_to_elements`.`page_id` = ? and `page_to_elements`.`page_id` is not null`, bindings `0 => 1`

Comment: @Ben, Ran `composer install --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader`, but still no luck

Comment: Please see my adapted question. It seems it has to do with this part `where('element_id', 1)`, but why?????

Comment: Apparently Eloquent casts integers as strings so this might be the core of the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26974914/laravel-eloquent-integers-returned-as-strings-in-mssql Try to use attribute casting and see if that helps.

Comment: But only on Linux? Cuz when I put the 1 in quotes it doesnt work on Windows anymore

Answer (score 0):

But what do you know, `$meta = $this->page->pageinfo->where('element_id', '1')->first();` works! But then again not on Windows.

So I wounded up adding an extra line `$id = 1;` and parsing that in the query.

Strange workaround though